# Javamail 1.5.1, Tomcat 7, and java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.mail.Authenticator

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, jakarta-mail

I trying to use Javamail 1.5.1 with Tomcat 7 and Eclipse Kepler.

When I try to send an email, Tomcat blows up with the error below...

From the docs, I understand that everything I need is now within the javax.mail.jar. And I have that in the webapp's WEB-INF/lib folder.

I think it's complaining that it can't find javax.mail.Authenticator. But I have confirmed that the class is within the jar.

This should be easy. Could someone please point out what I am missing?

I have also added the jar to eclipse preferences as a Library.

Also... where to I get the downloaded javadoc so I can add that to eclipse too? i.e. so I can hover the mouse over a word and get the docs?

Thanks

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/Authenticator
org.apache.naming.factory.MailSessionFactory.getObjectInstance(MailSessionFactory.java:106)
org.apache.naming.factory.ResourceFactory.getObjectInstance(ResourceFactory.java:143)
javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:321)
org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:843)
org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:154)
org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:831)
org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:168)
util.SendEmails.<init>(SendEmails.java:47)
...
```

Comment: You need to add it as an external jar in the build settings. Most people add this in the wrong tab. Its not the tab where it shows your JVM, but the one two tabs over. I don't have eclipse on this machine to verify, but should be in same preference pane.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I already had that. But no go still.

Comment: I don't think it's the library that's the problem. I think it relates to JNDI. I've done a dozen different variations - including what you mentioned. But still it can't find Authenticator - which is for sure in the jar. I've wasted at least 6 hours fighting with this...

Comment: If I run a simple example with the sessions parameters hard coded it work fine. But if I use any JNDI example, I get this error. my intention is to use straight SMTP. No authentication required. I also tried copying the example class to a standalone tomcat server. On start it died complaining about naming... WARNING: Failed to retrieve JNDI naming context for container [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[host.domain.com].StandardContext[]] so no cleanup was performed for that container
javax.naming.NamingException: No naming context bound to this class loader
I really don't get it.

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same issue, and I fixed this by adding the Java Mail jar to the tomcat lib directory.

I'm thinking the cause of the error is that during the JNDI lookup the classes from the webapp itself are not loaded, so in order for the JNDI to work you need to provide the jar directly to tomcat, instead of in your webapp.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to forget to add jars in Tomcat's lib into Tomcats classpath. Project -> Run As -> Run Configurations -> YourServer -> Classpath tab. That helped in my case. Simply copying files into tomcat's lib folder does not suffice.