# Eclipse, Javamail, Tomcat, and socket unreachable / network unreachable?

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-mail, vaadin

I have a regular Java Application that works with Javamail. As in, if I just run it in a Main(String[] args) it will work but if I'm running it from a webapp, **specifically VAADIN with Tomcat (AND Jetty)**, I always get a  java.net.SocketException: network is unreachable: connect

I can ping the MSExchange server. And the regular program works.

In eclipse, I tried following [this guide](http://www.scarba05.co.uk/blog/2013/01/sending-email-using-smtp-authentication-with-tomcat-jndi-resource/) by changing the server.xml and web.xml settings, but after adding in all th changes, I still get the same error.

This is the Java Application that works in Eclipse, it will send an email using the MSExchange server we have. Are there specific ports I need to add? I've tried to force Tomcat to use [IPV4 by adding 0.0.0.0 to all my connectors](http://www.fourproc.com/2012/04/20/force-tomcat-to-use-ipv4-on-server-with-both-ipv6-and-ipv4-configured.html) but that didn't do anything.

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Session;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public class SendEmail {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
          //Creates a connection with the Exchange Server.
        String smtpHostServer = "MSExchangeServerName";

        Properties props = System.getProperties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", smtpHostServer);
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "false");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "25");
        props.put("java.net.preferIPv4Stack","True");
        Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);

        String todayStr = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy").format(new Date());

        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 14);
        Date d = c.getTime();
        String dateStr = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").format(d);

        SendEmailUtility.sendEmail(session, "email@host.com", "Test <b>Email</b>");
```

Here is the SendEmailUtility:

```
import javax.activation.DataHandler;
import javax.activation.DataSource;
import javax.activation.FileDataSource;
import javax.mail.BodyPart;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;

public class SendEmailUtility {
    public static void sendEmail(Session session, String toEmail, String subject, String body){   
        try        
        {          
            //Create a default MimeMessage object.
         Message message = new MimeMessage(session);

         // Set From: header field of the header.
         message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("blah@test.com"));

         // Set To: header field of the header.
         message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,InternetAddress.parse(toEmail));

         // Set Subject: header field
         message.setSubject(subject);

         // This mail has 2 part, the BODY and the embedded image
         MimeMultipart multipart = new MimeMultipart("related");

         // first part (the html)
         BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
         String htmlText = "<img src=\"cid:image\"><p>"+body;
         messageBodyPart.setContent(htmlText, "text/html");
         // add it
         multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

         // second part (the image)
         messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
         String fdsImg;
        fdsImg = "c:\download.jpg";

         DataSource fds = new FileDataSource(fdsImg);

         messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fds));
         messageBodyPart.setHeader("Content-ID", "<image>");

         // add image to the multipart
         multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

         // put everything together
         message.setContent(multipart);
         // Send message
         Transport.send(message); //ERROR HAPPENS HERE ON TOMCAT
        }
        catch (Exception e) {          
            e.printStackTrace();        
        }    
    }
}
```

This is the exactly same copy pasted code in the webapp with the exact same EmailUtils above, only that this version DOESN'T WORK.

```
btnSendEmail.addClickListener(new ClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
            try {
                String smtpHostServer = "MSExchangeServerName";

                Properties props = System.getProperties();
                props.put("mail.smtp.host", smtpHostServer);
                props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "false");
                props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "25");
                props.put("java.net.preferIPv4Stack","True");
                Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);

                String todayStr = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy").format(new Date());

                Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 14);
                Date d = c.getTime();
                String dateStr = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").format(d);

                SendEmailUtility.sendEmail(session, "blah@test.com", "test <b>email");


            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Notification.show("Error sending the email", Notification.Type.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
        }

       });


       layout.addComponent(btnSendEmail);
```

My Stacktrace:

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: MSExchangeName, port: 25;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.SocketException: Network is unreachable: connect
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1972)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:642)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:295)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:125)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:194)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
    at org.test.EmailUtils.sendEmail(EmailUtils.java:57)
```

Are there any other options I have to do or that I might not have done correctly? As a shot in the dark, I tried looking up eclipse, javamail, tomcat and I [got this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21346643/javamail-1-5-1-tomcat-7-and-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-javax-mail-authe/22457204#22457204) and added the Javamail jar to my Tomcat Lib folder and also in my classpath. I still get the cannot connect error.

When I Right Click > Run as >Run on server, I tried to see if Tomcat was running on a system account, but when I checked in Task Manager, it had my Username under here:

[image]

Does this mean it has access to the network? Or something is still blocked? Or I need to add proxy settings specifically for Tomcat?

Comment: Can you telnet from to port 25 of your exchange server?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that, but I probably don't have permission from the network admins.  I know I can access the exchange server from my computer, if that's what you mean? In the first example, the Hostname and Port work PERFECTLY. The second one can't connect. I'm running both programs from the same computer in Eclipse.

Comment: To be clear, both programs are running on your desktop/laptop computer, in Eclipse, and one works but the other one fails?  And from that same computer can you [use telnet to connect to the Exchange server](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#condebug)?  If telnet works, and the standalone program works, and only Tomcat fails, check your firewall and anti-virus settings.

Comment: @BillShannon I finally got permission to uninstall our antivirus and check. You were right, it was the antivirus. The emails came through after I uninstalled it. If you want to make the answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a firewall or anti-virus problem.  The JavaMail FAQ has [connection debugging tips](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#condebug).